# how to create a list in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var d = $("#nw-dns_ip1_addr").val()+','+$("#nw-dns_ip2_addr").val(); 
            server_ip = [d.replace(/^,|,$/,"")]; //this will remove start and end comma
            alert(server_ip);
```

Am getting  190.82.0.56,170.20.0.20. I need it "190.82.0.56","170.20.0.20" like list.

But it should be handled when i have single value also

var d = $("#nw-dns_ip1_addr").val(); in this case am getting '"'$("#nw-dns_ip1_addr").val()'"'

"190.82.0.56","" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put double quotes in single quote.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ZycUd/)**

```
var d ='"'+ $("#nw-dns_ip1_addr").val()+'","'+$("#nw-dns_ip2_addr").val() + '"'; 
server_ip = [d.replace(/^,|,$/,"")]; //this will remove start and end comma
alert(server_ip);
```

**Edit** for single ip address

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ZycUd/1/)**

```
var d ='"'+ $("#nw-dns_ip1_addr").val()+'"'; 
server_ip = [d.replace(/^,|,$/,"")];
```